# restrict mercurial repo access

Tags: mercurial

i have a mercurial server 
i edited access.conf in hgadmin repo as following:

```
deny repo=a/b
read user=x/**
read user=y/**

write repo=a/b user=x/abc
write repo=a/b user=y/z
```

but user z still can't access this repo, any ideas ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How is user z trying to access this? What error message is user z getting? Without more detail, this could be anything from "hgadmin has not re-read its config" to "user z hasn't plugged in their network cable"

Comment: z user account try to clone that repo as following : "hg clone ssh://hg@repoUrl.com/path/to/repo" 
and the error appeared to that user :
remote: mercurial-server: access denied
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!